# Bash replace a comma with space colon space sequence

Tags: bash

I want to replace all commas in my file with a space, colon and space. I keep getting the error "Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats". Here is my command, where am I going wrong?

```
tr -d "," " : " < testfile
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tr -d` is usually used for *deleting* characters. If you want a quick way to replace commas with a `space-colon-space` sequence<sup>1</sup>, just use:

```
sed 's/,/ : /g' testfile
```

Once you're happy with the output, you can used `sed -i` to replace the original file, if that's what you want:

```
sed -i.bak 's/,/ : /g' testfile
```

That will modify the file, leaving the original contents in `testfile.bak`. If your `sed` isn't advanced enough to have the `-i` option, you can do it manually:

```
mv testfile testfile.bak
sed 's/,/ : /g' testfile.bak >testfile
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're just trying to replace commas with colons (with *no* surrounding spaces), you can still use `tr`:

```
tr ',' ':' <testfile
```

or using the same `-i`-emulation as for less advanced `sed` implementations if you want to modify the original file:

```
mv testfile testfile.bak
tr ',' ':' <testfile.bak >testfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm deciphering what you're looking for correctly, `sed` is probably a better tool for this.  `tr` does substitution, but only for single characters.  If multiple characters are given it expects them to be a list of find and replacements, e.g.:

```
$ echo "hi"| tr "ih" "on"
no
```

It replaces i with o and h with n to make hi into no.

You're also using the `-d` switch, which is to delete characters.

To use sed though, you'd want something like this:

```
sed 's/,/ : /g' input > output
```

Depending on the version of `sed` used you may be able to use the `-i` switch to act on the file in place and avoid the redirect and new file.

`sed` is a stream editor that reads by lines, so this will go line by line through the file and replace each comma with a colon surrounded by spaced.

`sed` is very powerful and you should read up on it if you want to use it more, but the simple syntax used here is `'s/regex/replacement/g'` with the `g` at the end meaning global, or replace all.

Answer (score 0):

just take out the -d and your command works.  You probably just want to take the spaces from around your colon.  It will take sequences of both sets and replace them.  so your replacing your comma with a space with what you have.